# Pallet Converge freezes with VirtualBox

Tags: clojure, virtualbox, pallet

My cider and lein REPLs freeze when I'm trying to "converge" a virtualbox machine.  This happens on step 2 of [step 5](https://github.com/pallet/pallet-vmfest#step-5-spin-up-an-instance).  I found [this issue](https://github.com/pallet/pallet-vmfest/issues/14) in [pallet-vmfest](https://github.com/pallet/pallet-vmfest).  Can anyone help with this?  If not, is there not much activity on [pallet](https://github.com/pallet/pallet) lately?  I noticed the last commit was April 15th, 2014.

Comment: What version of virtualbox? (must be >=4.3)
did you succeed in downloading the image (do you see it in ~/.vmfest/models)
if these worked it may help to join #pallet on irc.freenode.net and ask. We try to be around most of the time.

Comment: look in the "develop" branch for the latest changes to pallet.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt, I'm using Virtualbox 4.3.16, and I downloaded the image successfully.  I posted a couple times in #pallet and didn't get any replies.